# Facing a Problem with "Remember Me" Functionality in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I tried the below code to perform the "remember me" functionality. It's Working fine. But, here I'm facing one problem. If I selected a checkbox with written both values and entered another screen. When I changed both values and It's required to be checked and unchecked checkbox. After, It's a store to the registry. I need it here. **It does not need to checked and unchecked checkbox every time**. Does anyone know what should I mistake here and anything missing?

```
@IBAction func rememberMeAction(_ sender: UIButton) {        
if checkBoxBtn.isSelected == false {

         UserDefaults.standard.set(loginID.text!, forKey: "firstvalue")
         UserDefaults.standard.set(loginPWD.text!, forKey: "secondvalue")
         checkBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "checked.png"), for: .normal)
         UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "checkBoxStatus")
         checkBoxBtn.isSelected = true
}
else {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "firstvalue")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "secondvalue")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            
        checkBoxBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "unchecked.png"), for: .normal)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "checkBoxStatus")
        checkBoxBtn.isSelected = false
   }
}
```

Comment: Nobody even knows whatever you call a checkbox and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question is a response to an event.

I suppose that this is bind to the `Value Changed` event of a Switch element. So what is happening is that, when a user click the switch, the value changes (i.e. from Off to On) then your code is called, toggling the Switch selection (from On to Off).

You should not try to change the selected state of a Switch in an event related to this same Switch